# Sitecore JSS components and Sitecore MVC components in a single Experience Editor page

Tags: jss

Can you use Sitecore JSS components with Sitecore MVC components in the same Experience Editor page? If this does work, does it work with dynamic placeholders?

An example might be adding a Experience Editor configurable Sitecore JSS component to an existing Sitecore website with editable pages composed with Sitecore MVC components.

Another might be a blended team of Sitecore MVC developers building your average Sitecore components. Then you might have FEDs who want to build a complex component which needs to consume data from various APIs outside of Sitecore, but has label, text etc configurable from Sitecore and sits in the flow of the page.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure answering your own question is frowned upon but after reading all the documentation and watching the videos i think i can confirm 'YES', you can. Hope this saves someone else some time. If i've got this wrong please do correct me.

See example https://jss.sitecore.net/#/cookbook/recipes/embedded-wizard-sample

This module rocks!

Comment: Answering your own question is most certainly acceptable :)

Comment: I'll add that this is the only way to mix the two at the this time, since it allows the MVC and JSS to render independently, then come together on the client side.

Comment: Great thanks @techphoria414 :)